# FInd the total number of orders and total number of sales which are having sale value greater than 2000 in a single sql query

Tags: sql

INPUT DATA :

```
Customer_ID order_number    order_value
1                  1      500
1                  2      300
1                  3      2400
1                  4      2123
2                  5      300
2                  2      2400
```

Output Data:

```
Customer ID no. of orders   valuegt2000
1             4                   2
2             2                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax#Conditional_(CASE)_expressions) expression if your DBMS has support for it.

This statement works fine at least in PostgreSQL:

```sql
select
  customer_id as "customer id",
  count(order_number) as "no. of orders",
  sum(
    case
      when order_value > 2000 then 1
      else 0
    end
  ) as valuegt2000
from
  my_table
group by
  customer_id
```